# UITableViewCell with StackView not dynamically sizing height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains a `StackView` with top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to the content view of the cell.

When I set up my `tableView`, I give it an estimated height and also set the rowHeight to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

In my `cellForRowAt` datasource method, I dequeue the cell and then call `cell.setup()` which adds any given number of views to my cell's stackView.

**The problem is**: My cell is always being sized to the estimated height of 80p. No matter how many views I add to the cell's stackView, it all crams into 80p height. The stackView, and thus the cell, isn't growing with each new item I insert into the cell before returning it in `cellForRowAt` datasource method.

I tried different distribution settings for my stackView, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you implement `heightForRowAt` where you're returning 80? If so, you shouldn't be doing that. If not, do the *"any given number of views"* that you're adding have height constraints? If not, that is likely the issue.

Comment: In order for dynamic sizing of cells to work the cells content must be able to define the height it self.  The `UIStackView` can't do this because it adjusts the size of it's contents to fit it's own size not the other way around.  So nothing inside the cell is able to tell the cell what size it should be.

Comment: @DonMag I'm not implementing that and I don't think I'm adding height constraints to those so maybe that is the issue? I'm not near my pc but I'll check this asap

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth So is there any solution then? DonMag mentioned giving height constraints to the views of the stackView

Comment: It all depends on what kind of layout you are trying to achieve.  Something inside the cell must be able to define the height so either the `UIStackView` it self needs to be a fixed height or you can use something else instead to contain the views.  Giving the sub views of the `UIStackView` probably wouldn't work because the point of the it is to adjust the size of it's subviews to fit itself

Comment: @Brejuro - if the views you are adding to the stack view do not have intrinsic heights, you have to *give* them heights in one way or another. A `UILabel`, for example, *does* have an intrinsic height. A `UIImageVIew` does *not*, so if you're adding that to your stack view you have to give it a height value. What types of views are you adding?

Comment: @DonMag I'm adding `UIButton`s but not giving them a frame, this seems like the problem then hm. @UpholderOfTruth seems to think it might not be a fix though, I guess I will have to check once I get back to my computer

Comment: @Brejuro  for a button you don't have to give a height hook left&right with labelTitle lines = 0 should do the job

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - `UIStackView` can be used in different ways. One is to arrange **and size** the subviews. Another way is to arrange, but **let the subviews** determine the size. In the case of auto-sizing cells, the latter is generally the purpose.

Comment: @DonMag I fully agree it can be used in both those ways but the original question didn't mention what kind of views were being added so we can't just jump to the conclusion that it can be fixed by giving them fixed heights.  I was agreeing with your comment about avoiding unnecessary manual calculations.  All I am saying is that if we are going to suggest fixing the heights of the views then at least say why it is needed and perhaps mention other options.  E.g. the heights need to be fixed because the views are not providing enough information to determine their intrinsic content size.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - sure... which is why my comment included a question about what types of views the OP is using. Tough to say "this" will or won't work, *or* to offer a reasonable solution, without further clarification of what all is going on.

Comment: @DonMag sorry I meant your comment against the other answer not your comment against the original question.  That comment was spot on.  I was commenting on the other answer and your comment against it.  (A lot of confusing commenting in this comment)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple demonstration of adding buttons to a stack view inside an auto-sizing table view cell:

```
class StackOfButtonsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var theStackView: UIStackView!

    func setup(_ numButtons: Int) -> Void {

        // cells are reused, so remove any previously created buttons
        theStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        for i in 1...numButtons {
            let b = UIButton(type: .system)
            b.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            b.backgroundColor = .blue
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }

    }

}


class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StackOfButtonsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! StackOfButtonsTableViewCell

        cell.setup(indexPath.row + 1)

        return cell

    }

}
```

Assuming you have created a prototype cell, and its only content is a `UIStackView` configured as:

```
Axis: Vertical
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Equal Spacing
Spacing: 8
```

and you have it constrained Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom to the cell's content view, this is the result:

[image]

No need for any height calculations, and, since buttons *do* have intrinsic size, no need to set height constraints on the buttons.

Comment: I had a slightly different problem than the asker, but was hoping to gain context. Thanks to a thorough explanation, I did! Thanks. I needed this part: 
// cells are reused, so remove any previously created buttons